# how to determine if one variable is greater than 2 other variables in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

i know how to determine if one variable is greater than another in visual basic

```
Dim dbl_Boat1Total As Double = 10
Dim dbl_Boat2Total As Double = 5


 If (dbl_Boat1Total > dbl_Boat2Total) Then
            lbl_Boat1Rank.Text = "1"
        End If
```

but how do i determine if one variable is greater than 2 other variables?

```
Dim dbl_Boat1Total As Double = 10
Dim dbl_Boat2Total As Double = 5
Dim dbl_Boat3Total As Double = 2.5
```

Comment: test them both? `If (dbl_Boat1Total > dbl_Boat2Total And dbl_Boat1Total > dbl_Boat3Total)` for instance...

Comment: Take some time to learn about Boolean logic.  I thought everyone learned the basics in maths class.

Comment: You can add them to a new `List(Of Double)` and examine what the `Max` function returns.

Comment: @JQSOFT That just gives you the max value. Doesn't help determine which variable is greater than others.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim dbl_Boat1Total As Double = 10
Dim dbl_Boat2Total As Double = 5
Dim dbl_Boat3Total As Double = 2.5

If (dbl_Boat1Total > dbl_Boat2Total AndAlso dbl_Boat1Total > dbl_Boat3Total) Then
        lbl_Boat1Rank.Text = "1"
End If
```

I think there's no way to compare if one variable is greater than 2 or more other variables.

Use a AndAlso operator:
if (statement1) AndAlso (statement2)

if statement1 is false, then vb.net doesn't run the second one, this is good in this situation i think, in other situations you can use the classic And operator.

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dbl_Boat1Total As Double = 10  
Dim dbl_Boat2Total As Double = 5 
Dim dbl_Boat3Total As Double = 2.5>  

If (dbl_Boat1Total > dbl_Boat2Total) And (dbl_Boat1Total > dbl_Boat3Total) Then
lbl_Boat1Rank.Text = "1"  
End If
```